# HTML (4.01) "lang" attribute: Best practice / Browser compat for where to place: HTML or BODY?

Tags: html, lang-attribute

I'm just creating a new site from scratch. Each page in that site will have a default language and I'd like the markup to reflect it because there will be multiple languages.

I'm using HTML 4.01 and I'm targetting older browsers as well (e.g. IE 6, Opera 8, Lynx etc.). Regarding cross-browser compatibility as well as of "best practices" where to place the [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html): To the `HTML` tag or to the `BODY` tag or does this make no difference at all?

I'm going towards the `BODY` tag as it contains all the default languages text, while the `HEAD` might not always. But I have no clue if any browser is taking care of the `lang` attribute anyway. Any hints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any cross-browser compatibility issues AFAIK. But it makes the most sense and is most commonly used by putting it in `html` since your document isn't just limited to `body`. See [this page](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/lang) for the purpose of `lang` and [this page](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-http-and-lang) for the proper use of `lang` versus other ways of specifying language.

Since `lang` only specifies the language of the current element and its child elements, unless you place it in your root element (`html`), you're neglecting a large part of your document (what language is your title, meta description, etc.?). You can, however, add additional `lang` attributes in other elements further down your document tree if they are in a different language.

More documents outlining best practices:

- http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/language-decl/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-lang/

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That's basically what I thought as well but wanted to have a second opinion. Regarding the links you provided, in particular your second link to the FAQ on W3C was very helpful. Thanks a lot!